# Load different rootfs partition using Uboot in raspberry compute module 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, u-boot

I am trying to load different rootfs in raspberry pi lite os using Uboot application .
I want to load /dev/mmcblk0p5 as default ,if it fails load /dev/mmblk0p3 as backup rootfs.
I written application in Uboot to load different root partition based on corrupt partition.
But i am unable to load another partition ,only one default partition  is loading.
In cmdline.txt root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 is there as default ,how to change to support  two rootfs ,what to write in cmdline.txt file to support two rootfs base on uboot selection partition

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "I written application in Uboot to load different root partition based on corrupt partition."

Comment: cmdlinte.txt is what is used by the Raspbian firmware to set the kernel command line. U-Boot uses the content of environment variable bootargs. You could create a script boot.scr using mkimage to iterate over partitions. Or you can set up UEFI variables in U-Boot using the efidebug command and let the boot manager iterate through the partitions. Or if you work interactively you might install GRUB to choose your OS.